# Can getExternalFilesDir() return different paths based on context?

Tags: android

For example, are all of these guaranteed to return the same result for an application?

- `getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir()`
- `this.getExternalFilesDir()` (`this` is `SomeActivity`)
- `this.getExternalFilesDir()` (`this` is `SomeOtherActivity`)
- `this.getExternalFilesDir()` (`this` is `SomeService`)
- etc.

The same goes for similar methods, e.g., `getExternalCacheDir()`, `getFilesDir()`, `openFileOutput()`, etc.

I imagine that yes, it is the base singleton application context which defines where media can be stored for an application.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() doesn't take a Context object as parameter. All of them need a string as parameter. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

> are all of these guaranteed to return the same result for an application?

Well, the latter three will fail to compile. I assume you mean "the parameter is an instance of the `Activity` or `Service` that I mention here".

If I am correct in my assumption, none of the `Context` objects that you are citing should change the result. However, bear in mind that the actual *path* may vary, based on the user that is running your app, for devices with 2+ accounts set up.

Comment: Well, all four would fail to compile, I hastily put the Context as a parameter instead of the caller. :) I've clarified the syntax (but your assumption is correct).